# calculating football score in Excel

Tags: excel, formula, worksheet-function

Hopefully someone can help.
I am running a prediction league in work.  To help me calculate scores I thought I would use Excel.
These are the conditions for my league

- Exact score = 3 pts
- Points for correct goal difference = 2pts, i.e. if predicted score is 2-2 and the actual score is 1-1 then goal difference in both case =0 goals, so 2pts should be awarded
- Correct result but wrong score = 1pt (home or away win)

Can't post images so here is a quick mockup

```
-  HOME        HOME    AWAY    AWAY        Home    Away    Pts
-   Norwich     0       0       West Ham    1       1       2
-   Arsenal     3       1       Southampton 7       2       1
-   Aston Villa 2       0       Swansea     0       1       0
-   Fulham      3       0       West Brom   1       1       0
-   Man Utd     4       0       Wigan       2       0       1
-   Q.P.R.      0       0       Chelsea     0       0       3
-   Stoke       1       1       Man City    1       3       0
-   Sunderland  1       2       Liverpool   1       2       3
-   Reading     1       3       Tottenham   0       2       2
-   Everton     2       0       Newcastle   4       1       1
```

Comment: -1 Because you haven't tried anything. Try and ask questions about where you failed.This shouldn't be too hard, hell if you make it dead simple you need only very basic formulas like SUM() and AVERAGE() or whatever calculation you want to make.

Comment: And in all cases I don't see how this is related to programming. This belongs to superuser.

Comment: I have tried and failed but I can't upload a workbook or a screenshot.  My formula is =IF(COUNT(C3:G3)=4,(F3=C3)*(G3=D3)*2+CHOOSE(SIGN(C3-D3)+2,2,3,1)*(SIGN(C3-D3)=SIGN(F3-G3)),"").

Comment: apologies - I pressed return there for a new line and it submitted my comment.  My formula doesn't seem to work out the goal difference.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur I disagree with your second comment, the question is about programming - yes, in excel and at a basic level, but both of these facts don't make it less of a programming question.

Comment: I am confused. I submitted a question to Stackoverflow and added tags of Excel and formula, which is what my question is about, but you keep going on about programming?

Comment: SO is a programming/coding community.

Comment: I take your point, but I see lots of Excel questions on SO not directly related to programming hence the reason why I thought I would post my question in the same spirit.  Regards

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work. Assuming that one set of results is in A1:B1 and the other in C1:D1. Home team listed first as usual in UK football fixtures.

`=IF(AND(A1=C1,B1=D1),3,IF((A1-B1)=(C1-D1),2,IF(SIGN(A1-B1)=SIGN(C1-D1),1,0)))`